# Do Ruby objects have a built in getter/setter methods?

Tags: ruby

In some languages, you can access attributes of an object without writing your own getter/setter methods.

Do objects have built in getter/setter with Ruby?

Here is what I'm trying:

```
class Obj
  def initialize(color)
    @color = color
  end
end

t = Obj.new("red")

puts t.color
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [`attr_accessor :color`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) if you want just the run of the mill auto-generated getters/setters.

> Defines a named attribute for this module, where the name is symbol.id2name, creating an instance variable (@name) and a corresponding access method to read it. Also creates a method called name= to set the attribute. String arguments are converted to symbols.

There's also just an [`attr_reader :color`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) if you don't want to be able to set the value outside the class

> Creates instance variables and corresponding methods that return the value of each instance variable.

And [`attr_writer :color`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_writer) if you want to set, but not read, outside of the class.

> Creates an accessor method to allow assignment to the attribute.

```
class Obj
  attr_accessor :color

  def initialize(color)
    @color = color
  end
end

t = Obj.new("red")
t.color #=> "red"
```

Comment: Thanks this is much better than the work around I found and am using.

Answer (score 0):

I found that these methods seem to exist for all objects in Ruby:

```
t.instance_variable_set(:@color, "blue")
t.instance_variable_get(:@color)
```

Comment: That's really pointless unless you're setting the name dynamically, like `instance_variable_set('@' + name, 'blue')`